# SSIS ForceExecutionResult not working

Tags: ssis

I have a package, inside which contains a script task, due to probably C# library issues in some of the servers, this task may success in some machines but fail in others (reporting `Cannot load script for execution`).

I want to force the task to be success by setting the `ForceExecutionResult = Success` option for this task. However when running, I found this doesn't work, the task still fails in the old-fashioned way.

I don't want to modify the `MaxErrorCount` for package because I want to reveal errors from other components, in the meanwhile, even this script task fails during validation, I want the package report success, is there any way to make the solution?

Answer (score 0):

To let your package continue execution, you can set the DelayValidation property to True on the Script Task (so the package will begin executing), then on the Precedence Constraint that follows this Script Task, set it to continue on completion, instead of success.

Comment: I know this way can make the rest of my package run correctly, but package will finally report failure due to `MaxErrorCount > 1`. I need a solution that not hide errors from other components, but void all errors from this component and make the whole package success.